# how to call a php function from confirmation dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

How to call a php function from confirmation dialog box, when we click "OK" button. I have done this using javascript. However it looks odd, when we compared to other dialogue boxes. The other dialog boxes in UIjquery. I am unable to fix at my end.
Else, It is possible to style the javascript confirmation dialog box?

Comment: use ajax function to call php on confirmation box

Comment: Do you have know any example are demo website pages for these type of occurrence?

Answer (score 1):

Ajax code to call php page

```
var answer = confirm('your message');
    if(answer)
    {
        data = 'hai';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "phppage.php",
            data: { data:data },   //If you want to pass data to php page
            success:function(response)
            {       
                //response from php page.
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert('clicked cancel..');
    }
```